# Can I stop one control covering another in windows forms?

Tags: c#

I'm using windows forms c# in visual studio 2019 I have a picture box, "pb_sheep_apex", and I am moving it a random location after it has been clicked. I have an "if" statement (code included below) to determine if the new random location is within the boundaries of another control, as I want it to remain in empty space and not cover any of the HUD.

```
Rectangle sheep = new Rectangle(pb_sheep_easy.Location, pb_sheep_easy.Size);
Rectangle timer = new Rectangle(lbl_timeRemaining.Location, lbl_timeRemaining.Size);
Rectangle healthBar = new Rectangle(lbl_healthBounds.Location, lbl_healthBounds.Size);

            if(sheep.IntersectsWith(timer) || sheep.IntersectsWith(healthBar))
            {
                Reposition(Width, Height, pb_sheep_easy, pb_sheep_hard, pb_sheep_apex);
            }
```

This if statement occurs when the pb_sheep_apex_LocationChanged event is triggered and checks if the picture box is within the boundaries of another control, which if true should call the reposition method until the picture is relocated to a position outside the boundaries of the control, however the picture box can somehow be displayed within the boundaries of the control. I cannot find a fault in the if statement but it doesn't function how I would like it to. If anyone could find the fault I would be very grateful. The following contains the code for the called reposition method:

```
protected Point Reposition(int width, int height, PictureBox sheep_easy, PictureBox sheep_hard, PictureBox sheep_apex)
        {
            int RandX;
            int RandY;
            Point position = new Point();

            switch (difficulty)
            {
                case 'e':
                    Random re = new Random();
                    RandX = re.Next(0, width - sheep_easy.Width);
                    RandY = re.Next(0, height - sheep_easy.Height);
                    position = new Point(RandX, RandY);
                    break;

                case 'h':
                    Random rh = new Random();
                    RandX = rh.Next(0, width - sheep_hard.Width);
                    RandY = rh.Next(0, height - sheep_hard.Height);
                    position = new Point(RandX, RandY);
                    break;

                case 'a':
                    Random ra = new Random();
                    RandX = ra.Next(0, width - sheep_apex.Width);
                    RandY = ra.Next(0, height - sheep_apex.Height);
                    position = new Point(RandX, RandY);
                    break;
            }

            Health();

            return position;
        }
```

The initial reposition, before checking if the control is within the boundaries of another:

```
//sheep targets clicked 
//
        private void pb_sheep_easy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            health--;

            if (score == 0)
            {
                timer_countdown.Start();
            }

            if (Death() == true)
            {
                pb_sheep_easy.Location = Reposition(Width, Height, pb_sheep_easy, pb_sheep_hard, pb_sheep_apex);
                score++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: please paste contents of `Reposition`

Comment: @LeiYang that's done now

Comment: `Reposition` has return type `Point` but where is the value used?

Comment: `Random re = new Random();`...`rh`...`ra`... yeah you probably noticed the re-declaration warning... Why not define one random engine at a higher scope? Maybe one static one for everything?

Comment: @LeiYang Sorry about that, hopefully you have enough code to understand now.

Comment: @JHBonarius I did have one random engine to begin with, but when the error occurred i broke it down further just to help ensure that wasn't causing an unexpected error